# PHP Get specific item from this type of array

Tags: php, arrays

I've tried out a bunch of the answers on here and figure this should be really simple.. trying to get into a hook for a woo pdf export plugin to integrate with ACF..

If I run this -

```
echo $this->order
```

I get this -

```
{"id":7,"parent_id":0,"status":"processing","currency":"GBP","vers
```

How can I pull out just the id aka first item?

Many thanks!

SOLUTION:

As per below essentially, the code I used that works is..

```
$thisOrd = $this->order;
$obj = json_decode($thisOrd);
echo $obj->id;
```

Thanks All.

Comment: That is a JSON String _Well a part of one_ So look up [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) in the manual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to decode the json string, into a stdObject

```
$obj = json_decode($this->order);
echo $obj->id; // 7
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$order = json_decode($this->order, true);
echo $order['id']
```

Comment: As he  like, he can use json_decode($this->order) and the result will be an instance of stdClass or json_decode($this->order, true) and the result will be an array

Answer (score 0):

convert it to array first

```
$arr = json_decode($this->order,true);
var_dump($arr['id'])
```